# Use of multiple parameter

Tags: c, function

Though I know it is possible to use multiple parameters, I just wanted to know if it is recommended to use multiple parameters, by multiple I mean ~20. And several of  my functions would use ~20 parameters.

I am doing these in replacement of global variables, are there any options I can use. However, we are not allowed to use arrays.

Sample code: (This returns the quantity of an item given its code, I've considered implementing this is the main function, but it is not ideal since I would need to getItemQty code multiple times.

```
long getItemQty (int nItemCode, int* lQty1001, int* lQty1002, int* lQty1003, int* lQty1004, int* lQty1005, int* lQty1006, int *lQty1007, int* lQty2001, int* lQty2002, int* lQty2003, int* lQty2004, int* lQty2005, int* lQty2006, int *lQty2007, int* lQty3001, int* lQty3002, int* lQty3003, int* lQty3004, int* lQty4001, int* lQty4002, int* lQty4003, int* lQty4004, int* lQty4005, int* lQty4006) {
switch (nItemCode) {
        case 1001: return *lQty1001;
        case 1002: return *lQty1002;
        case 1003: return *lQty1003;
        case 1004: return *lQty1004;
        case 1005: return *lQty1005;
        case 1006: return *lQty1006;
        case 1007: return *lQty1007;
        case 2001: return *lQty2001;
        case 2002: return *lQty2002;
        case 2003: return *lQty2003;
        case 2004: return *lQty2004;
        case 2005: return *lQty2005;
        case 2006: return *lQty2006;
        case 2007: return *lQty2007;
        case 3001: return *lQty3001;
        case 3002: return *lQty3002;
        case 3003: return *lQty3003;
        case 3004: return *lQty3004;
        case 4001: return *lQty4001;
        case 4002: return *lQty4002;
        case 4003: return *lQty4003;
        case 4004: return *lQty4004;
        case 4005: return *lQty4005;
        case 4006: return *lQty4006;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using a `struct` ?

Comment: I doubt we could use struct since I'm currently taking an intro to programming class

Comment: Can you give us an example of a function that takes 20 parameters?

Comment: Let me edit the post

Comment: if the parameters are linear and are similar to each other then use an array

Comment: I've considered the use of arrays, but we are restricted only to the functions that have been taught

Comment: General Rule - NO. If you have to pass more than 4 -- you should look at refactoring your function.

Comment: Are you sure you understood the requirements correctly? You can certainly have a function with so many parameters (unless its so many that the stack overflows). But it's definetely not good practice and real code would almost never be like that. An array is the right tool here. But if you say you can't use it then there is not much more we can say.

Comment: It looks like an array would be a good fit here. It is not normal for functions to take in 20 parameters; in some cases the `Builder` pattern can be used in OOP languages

Comment: I've been looking for an alternative which is similar to traversing an array and closest I could think of is using a for loop and switch statements together

Comment: I think you need to give the original problem that you are trying to solve. Because it sounds like this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That is, you are asking about Y (function args) because you think that is the solution to X. But you haven't told us what X is. That is, what is the problem you are trying to solve when you went to this attempted solution?

Comment: Given 24 quantities to keep track of (with arrays and structs not allowed), I would actually choose global variables over a function with 25 parameters. Your example even proves the point: the argument `int nItemCode` appears three times in the argument list (i.e. the list is so long that it's unreadable).

Comment: BTW, you don't actually need pointers for that function. You could just have `int lQty1001` and `case 1001: return lQty1001;`

Comment: @kaylum, we are required to create a program that is sort of like a shopping which can add or reduce the number item, remove all items, display what is inside the cart, and print the receipt.

Comment: @user3386109 agreed, this is just a sample, I've got an almost similar function which adds/reduce the number of items. Like *lItem1001 += lQty

Comment: I think you should speak to your teaching staff to clarify the requirements. On the face of it, it does not make sense to solve such a problem with the constraints you have given (ie, no structs and no arrays). Otherwise you may be going in the totally wrong direction. Correctly understanding the requirements is the first (and arguably most important) part of software dev but that's not something we can help you with here.

Comment: @kaylum I have already the specifications several times, and I'm sure that I understood it correctly. I think it aims to test our understanding of the specific topic

Comment: What happens when `nItemCode` is 5000?  It shouldn't happen, but …

Comment: Making a shopping cart without using arrays and/or structs seems pretty insane to me. Maybe you should explain what the _exact_ requirement is.

Comment: The items being sold only contains a limited number of items

Comment: In your function declaration there is more than one parameter named nItemCode. This makes me think that something is wrong. Clarify better, may be some idea comes out.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, that was a typo. I'll update it

Comment: Is it possible that you are supposed not to use arrays, but a different data structure like a linked list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very curious and I suspect there is still something to unveil.
So, this answer is curious too and I suspect it can unveil something new.

A (poor) idea that comes to my mind is to make things a little more readable, something like this:

```
long getItemQty(int nItemCode, int q1, int q2, int q3, int q4, int q5, int q6, int q7) {
    switch (nItemCode % 1000) {
        case 1: return q1;
        case 2: return q2;
        case 3: return q3;
        case 4: return q4;
        case 5: return q5;
        case 6: return q6;
        case 7: return q7;
    }
}

if (nItemCode < 5000) res = getItemQty(nItemCode, lQty4001, lQty4002, lQty4003, lQty4004, lQty4005, lQty4006, 0);
if (nItemCode < 4000) res = getItemQty(nItemCode, lQty3001, lQty3002, lQty3003, lQty3004, 0,         0,       0);
if (nItemCode < 3000) res = getItemQty(nItemCode, lQty2001, lQty2002, lQty2003, lQty2004, lQty2005, lQty2006, lQty2007);
if (nItemCode < 2000) res = getItemQty(nItemCode, lQty1001, lQty1002, lQty1003, lQty1004, lQty1005, lQty1006, lQty1007);
```

In both cases, original version with long switch and many parameters and this one with fewer parameters, some macro could help; for short-parameter-version this macro:

```
#define FUNC(code, nf) \
  if (code < 5000) res = nf(code, lQty4001, lQty40002... \
  ...(basically the same four lines above)...
```

can be called in the main with

```
res = FUNC(nItemCode, getItemQty);
```

But all depends on the final application. A macro could also be used to generate the long declaration and the long switch in getItemQty(), perhaps OR instead. Macros can (and should) be used to avoid to be too much repetitive.

--EDIT--

Actually the macro could be more general: it could avoid to refer to a perhaps undeclared "res" variable; but it seems less nice.

There are two possible ways:

1. Leave the macro as is, and use something like this in the main:

   int res;
   FUNC(itemcode_im_interested_in, func_to_call) 
   // will expand to something like res = func_to_call(...)
2. Redefine the macro as follows:

> ```
> #define FUNC(res, code, nf) \
> if (code < 5000) res = nf(code, lQty4001, lQty40002... \
> ...
> ```

and call the macro in the main with

```
int res = FUNC(res, nItemCode, getItemQty);
```

I like more the first form for aesthetic reasons, but the second form is more clean and versatile.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great idea, it will definitely make my codes shorter and more readable.

Comment: May I ask what res stands for? Or is it just a variable that stores the returned value?

Comment: @Janjan yes, it is only a variable to hold the returned result. But then there is an error in the macro declaration. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not optimal.

Multiple parameters increase code size at the call site, more or less linearly.(Each scalar argument is typically a `mov` or a `push` instruction).

Also, modern platforms pass the first couple of arguments through registers, of which there's a limited number, typically 4-6. Once you exceed that number, parameters have to go through the stack, which is a little bit slower.

Concerning your example, you could pass a pointer to a `struct` and use a `switch` to select a member. If the variables are `const`, making them global (+preferably `static`) wouldn't be that bad either.